# How to get SOAP body with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I have incoming SOAP message in a format like this:

```
const soap = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body property="def">
        <Root>
            <Abc attr="abc">123456</Abc>
        </Root>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
`;
```

What I expect to get is the content of `<env:Body>` unchanged:

```
<Root>
    <Abc attr="abc">123456</Abc>
</Root>
```

To extract the body I use simple regex:

```
function getSoapBody(xmlStr) {
    let soapBody = null;
    if (xmlStr) {
        const soapBodyRegex = /<env:Body>([\s\S]*)<\/env:Body>/im;
        const soapBodyRegexMatchResult = xmlStr.match(soapBodyRegex);
        soapBody = soapBodyRegexMatchResult[1];
    }
    return soapBody;
}
```

However, getting body with regex is not ideal of course.

Moreover, I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I'm looking for a solution (or even npm package) that will basically getSoapBody regardless of prefix used (the regex above will fail if the prefix changes) or if there are optional attributes etc.

Comment: Have u tried this ; https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at this package and a couple more. Yet, I don't really need a server. I'd say I need to look for XML parsers instead... still investigating.

Comment: If you are making SOAP calls from your app, then it does have client support : https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#client.  If you just receiving the SOAP response, then you are right on the XML parsers.

Comment: The problem with XML parsers is that is parses everything, i.e. soap envelope and content of soap body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use xml2js to parse:

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var builder = new xml2js.Builder();

const soap = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body optional="abc">
        <Root>
            <Abc attr="1">123456</Abc>
        </Root>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
`;

var options = {explicitArray: false, tagNameProcessors: [xml2js.processors.stripPrefix] };

xml2js.parseString(soap, options, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('An error has occurred: ' + err);
        return;
    } 

    // Get the soap body object
    var soapBody = result.Envelope.Body;

    // Remove optional attribute(s) from <Body> element.
    if (soapBody.$) {
        delete soapBody.$;
    }

    // Get the body XML if needed
    var soapBodyXML = builder.buildObject(soapBody);

    console.log(soapBodyXML);
});
```

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect! The only issue I see is when I add an attribute to `<Body>` tag. For example: `<soapenv:Body attr="abc">` then `soapBodyXML` will have an unwanted parent element: `<root attr="abc">`

Comment: If I add `ignoreAttrs: true` to options then parser removes ALL attributes, i.e. from parent element (what I want) and from all elements inside body (which I don't want).

Comment: I notice that issue, you definitely don't want to use the ignoreAttrs, because there might be attributes you wish to access in the SOAP body. I'm sure it's possible to get the desired behaviour by specifying the options in the parser/builder.

Comment: I've modified your answer and will accept it now. This does the trick and I get what I expect in all cases. @Terry Lennox Thanks

Comment: Great! I spent some time looking for a nice solution for this myself. The XML namespaces cause a lot of grief when dealing with SOAP envelopes.

Comment: Hi @Ourang-ZebKhan, could you create a new question maybe for this, including your code?

Answer (score 3):

I used the fast-xml-parser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser/v/2.9.0) to achieve this by using the below options to exclude namespaces & prefixes and to ensure that attributes are under a node 'attr':

```
async function stripBodyFromSoapEnvelope(inputBody){
    const xmlParser = require('fast-xml-parser');        
    let options = {
            attributeNamePrefix : '',
            attrNodeName: 'attr',
            ignoreNameSpace: true,
            ignoreAttributes: false
        };
    const soapenv = xmlParser.parse(inputBody,options);
    return(soapenv.Envelope.Body);
}
```

Hope this helps.